# Leaflet: How to avoid high file count for custom layers?

Tags: leaflet

For my non-commercial, low-traffic web site, I successfully use Leaflet with standard raster tile layers from well-known sources.

I'd like to add additional layers containing very localized high-resolution maps. I've succeeded in making a usable raster tile-set from such a map, hosting the tiles on my own server, and adding that as an additional layer. But this creates a huge file count.  My cheap  shared-hosting account promises unlimited storage but limits file (actually, inode) counts.  If I add one more such tile-set, I risk getting thrown off my server.

Clearly I can look for a hosting account with higher limits, and I'm exploring Cloud alternatives, too.  (Comments welcome!)

Any other ideas?  Are there free or very low-cost alternatives for non-commercial ventures to use for low-traffic tile storage?

Or:  As I look at the localized, high-resolution maps – I see I could fairly easily trace them to create vector artwork without much loss of data -- and some gains in clarity.  I use Adobe Illustrator.  Is there a  reasonably painless way to get from an .ai  file (or some similar vector format) to a Leaflet layer?  With a substantially lower file count compared to the raster alternative?

Apologies if I've misused terminology --please correct me-- or if I've cluelessly missed some incredibly obvious way of solving this problem.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for [Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles) plugin: ([demo](http://ivansanchez.gitlab.io/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles/demo/demo.html))

> A [LeafletJS](http://www.leafletjs.com/) plugin to load tilesets in [`.mbtiles` format](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec).

The idea is to write your Tiles into a single `.mbtiles` file (actually an SQLite database), so that you just need to host that single file on your server, instead of your thousands of individual tiles.

The drawback is that visitors now need to download the entire file before the map can actually display your tiles. But then navigation is extremely smooth, since tiles no longer need to be fetched from the network, but are all locally available to the browser.

As for generating the `.mbtiles` file, there are many [implementations](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/wiki/Implementations) that can do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your response, complete with links.

Great to know that my issue is a good match with an established methodology!  

In past glances at MBTiles, I did not get at all that the SQLite database is downloadedr.  Can you say more about the impact on visitors' computers?  Is any prep, say, a browser extension, needed?  Are the .mbtiles files well-managed and promptly deleted when the page is closed?  My visitors are nearly all non-tekkies and I need to be extremely gentle with them.

Not sure non-tekkies will accept a significant delay.   I'll need to try a test case or two.

Comment: Ckick on the demo and see for yourself.